# Coloring the Row - ExpirationDate

Tags: c#, date

Table wont color, cant figure it out why, i did everything ok, and still nothing. When i put (now > expirationDate) nothing happend, but when i put "<" its colored. I think the problem is on expiration date function.
This is my code:

```
                private void button2_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime datum = DateTime.Now;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var expirationDate = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
            var vremesada = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
            var sevenDayBefore = expirationDate.AddDays(-7);

            if (now > sevenDayBefore && now < expirationDate)
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
            else if (now > expirationDate)
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            /*
           if (expirationDate > DateTime.Now)
           {
               row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
           }
           else if (sevenDayBefore < DateTime.Now()
           {
               row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;  
           }*/
        }
    }
```

Picture: http://prntscr.com/6pzgiv

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint and checking the value returned by `DateTime.Parse`.?

Comment: I checked and its good, everythins is showing good..Can you see the code  through TW?

Comment: Do not use `ToString()` and check the results ;)

Comment: Its showing a valid date..But still no colored row

Comment: Does the debugger enter your `else if` clause? If so, the problem may be that your `DataGridView` is not updating its display settings, even though the `BackColor` property is being set behind the scenes.

Comment: Its working when i set "<" instead of ">", every row is same color..

Comment: Did you check whether months and dates are correct when you gathered from data grid view?

Comment: I fixed it..default format is MM/D/YYYY but in form is DD/MM/YYYY...that was the problem...thanks all